# Run two shell file with thread

Tags: bash

How i can run two file shell in parallel and do not shared the same jvm. may be i use thread but how i run two file shell bu two thread ? File 1:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script for running several experimentations one the same JVM
# Usage : TRACE_DIR NB_EXPE Factories... 
#

param="parameter1"
another="parameter2"

for ((i = 10; i >= 0; i -= 1))
do
echo "run my file with param another " 
done
```

File 2 :

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Script for running several experimentations one the same JVM
# Usage : TRACE_DIR NB_EXPE Factories... 
#

a="101" b="400" c="500"

echo "run my programme with a b c "
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35294/run-two-shell-file-with-thread

Comment: "threads" don't exist when dealing with shell scripts - everything is run as separate processes. See lgarzo's answer for a way to run 2 scripts at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to run 2 shell scripts in parallel, you can use the following syntax:

```
script1 & script2 &
```

As an example take a look at the following test script (named `p1`):

```
i=1
while true;
do
    echo "1 $((i++))"
    sleep 1
    if [ $i -gt 10 ]; then break; fi
done
```

It will count to 10 and echo „1” before the counter. After 10 iterations it quits.

Now if you create a `p2` version, just modifying the `echo` a bit:

```
    echo "2 $((i++))"
```

Try to run the scripts with the above syntax:

```
$ ./p1 & ./p2 &
1 1
2 1
1 2
2 2
1 3
2 3
1 4
2 4
1 5
2 5
1 6
2 6
1 7
2 7
1 8
2 8
1 9
2 9
1 10
2 10
```

As you can see, both scripts display their output and quit after 10 rounds. Note that the output is mixed, so they run in parallel.